# Compare the results of a formula in one column with the actual number billed in another column to determine that they are the same or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to ensure that the result of a formula in Column Q is the same as the number in column R.  So at first I tried a simple `=Q5=R5` but the result was always false because Q5 is a formula `=(P5/100)` and I want to compare the result, not the formula itself.  P5 is also a formula `=(C5*I5)/4`
The image shows the columns I am referring to

[image]

Comment: You are probably encontering floating point decimal errors.  Try `=ROUND(Q5,2)=ROUND(R5,2)`

Comment: Thanks!  I so appreciate your help!

Comment: @SueBowman,, how U are getting Balance in Column R ?? I mean what Formula U have tried !

Answer (score 0):

The formulae in the P and Q columns need to be inserted using the `ROUND` function, i.e. the P column should be `=ROUND(C*I5/4,2)` and the Q column should be `=ROUND(P5/100,2)`.  Your `=Q=R` logical formula in the T column will then work.

The `ROUND` function, besides simply rounding any number, will also convert the output of a formula inside it to a number, that can then be compared with the T column. I did not know this before. Without the `ROUND` function a formula shows numbers on screen, but, as you have found out, it remains a formula and cannot be compared.

If the values in the R column are obtained from other formulae elsewhere on the spreadsheet then these too should be subject to the `ROUND` function.

All rounding should be to the same number of decimal places, otherwise the T column will show `FALSE`.

I have tried this using your table and different types of comparisons, e.g., logical (like yours), `IF`, style comparisons, etc. and have had consistent `FALSE TRUE TRUE` results in the T column.